# Recursion and function calling

Tags: c++, c, recursion

here are two different codes:

main function:

```
int main()
{
  int i=3+gets();   //it calls gets() and store value in i//
  return 0;
}
```

Recursive function:

```
int fact(n)
{
  if(n==0)
  return 1;
  int i=fact(n/2);   //Why fact() is not called here//
  return i;
}
```

My question is that:

Why fact() is not called at the time of initialization but in main() ,gets() is called?

Comment: This is really not very clear.  In both cases, the function is called when execution reaches the relevant line.

Comment: Where is gets() body?

Comment: What to do you mean "is not called at the time of initialization"?

Comment: I guess you forgot that the only function executed when a program is run is the function `main()`. Which, in your case, calls the function `gets()`, but not the function `fact()`.

Comment: ?? `gets` is a different function from `fact`, you call it when you want your code to do whatever `gets` does. Same with `fact`, other than to do what it does it calls itself a finite number of times.

Comment: it smell like n=0..really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two code snippets is that in the first code function main gets the control and its stetemnets are executed sequentially except brunch statements. So when statement

```
int i=3+gets();
```

gets the control function gets() is called.

In the second code snippet statement

```
int i=fact(n/2);
```

will not be executed until function fact() gets the control. You could to achieve the same effect if you would write for example

```
int main()
{
  int i= fact( 10 );
  return 0;
}
```

In this case function fact would be called and its body would be executed.

Also function fact() could be called if you would define a global variable that is outside any function and this global variable would contain an initializer that calls function fact(). For example

```
int j = fact( 10 );

int main()
{
  int i=3+gets();   //it calls gets() and store value in i//
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Also function fact() could be called if you would define a global variable that is outside any function and this global variable would contain an initializer that calls function fact(). For example_ `int j = fact( 10 );` : initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY And what?! It is C++.

Comment: Should be a note of C++, if it?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am sorry. I do not understand what you are speaking about

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there is an error in `int j = fact( 10 );` if it's C code. Since question is tagged as both C and C++ it might make sense to note that your code is C++ only. Nevertheless, I see no reason to downvote your answer.

Comment: @ Konstantin Oznobihin Why did you decide that it is a C code? The question has tag C++ and main is declared as int main() not int main( void ) as the C Standard requires.

Comment: @Konstantin Oznobihin You are wrong about implementation specific declarations of main. The implementation specific may only include some parameters but if it has no parameters it shall be declared as int main( void ). Read the C STandard and what means "implementation defined" relative to the main declaration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46593/discussion-between-konstantin-oznobihin-and-vlad-from-moscow)

Answer (score 0):

`gets()` won't be called during any "initialization", it will be called when execution reaches it. In your code that means it will be called immediately as it's the first action in `main`.

In your `fact` function you'll only get to the recursive call if the `if(n==0)` condition is false.

By the way, assuming by `fact` you mean factorial then your function is incorrect. It should be something like this:

```
int fact(int n)
{
  if(n == 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return n * fact(n - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: lol,it's not factorial :)

Comment: Calculating factorial via recursion is bad example for calculation factorial but good (popular) for explain recursion. And first condition may be n<2.

Comment: @alexolut - I know, I was just trying to flesh out his code without too many changes.

Answer (score 0):

gets() is the library function in C++ that reads characters from the standard input and stores them as a C string into string until a newline character or the end-of-file is reached.

please can you be clear about your intended meaning about "the time of initialization",you mean time of initialization of the program or the main() function?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am sorry but I have just joined and have not yet earned the reputation to comment.